# Can you use magic to create Corpses?

Tags: dnd-5e, necromancy

I’m trying to find the easiest and earliest way to obtain corpses magically.

My intent is to use the corpses in reanimation with the Animate Dead and Create Undead spells. Wish can pull off such a feat, but I can’t find any other spell than Wish that seems capable of accomplishing such a feat.

Comment: Why do the corpses have to be obtained magically?

Comment: @PJRZ I'd assume it's so that OP's character doesn't have to go around murdering people ^^

Comment: @PixelMaster: Just checking before suggesting a spade and a graveyard :) (Or paying somebody to do that for you - as used to happen in real life for medical experiments!)

Comment: @PJRZ Real life medical reanimation experiments? Do tell more :P

Comment: @David Coffron: Not for reanimation necessarily (though when it was discovered that electricity stimulated nerves...well, it did inspire the story of Frankenstein!). But body-snatching was an issue in 19th century Britain thanks to the surge in anatomical studies. Burke and Hare were the most notorious body-snatchers (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burke_and_Hare_murders). They ended up creating their own corpses. See also "resurrection men"

Comment: Thanks, I honestly didn’t see this question asked elsewhere so I appreciate the quick response!

Comment: Sure there is a spell to create corpses. It's called fireball and as material additionally requires a room full of low level NPCs.